# how to fix this error "Error in rep(yes, length.out = len) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'"

Tags: r, r-raster, rgdal

I have 2500 raster data and each raster can contain 1 or 2 or 3 layer. The problem is the best layer(the layer contain minimum NA values) for each raster need to be selected and I'd like to use R for this purpose. the sample data (contain 4 raster file) is uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O0W4cKsw0GrVUSHmc82ED2BoD1w0KAe2?usp=sharing):
in the first step, I'd like to select the best layer from the raster files that contain just 3 layers.
I use this code:

```
list_files <- list.files(pattern = ".tif")
file_name <- paste0("best_layer" , list_files)
library(raster)

for(i in 1:length(list_files)){
  r <- stack(list_files[i])
  len <- nlayers(r)
  if(len!=3)
    next
  r_1 <- sum(is.na(as.matrix(r[[1]])))
  r_2 <- sum(is.na(as.matrix(r[[2]])))
  r_3 <- sum(is.na(as.matrix(r[[3]])))
  ifelse((r_1 < r_2 & r_1 < r_3),print("layer1"),
         ifelse((r_2 < r_1 & r_2 < r_3)
                ,print("layer_2")
                ,print("layer_3")))
}
```

and the result is:

```
[1] "layer_1"
[1] "layer_1"
[1] "layer_2"
[1] "layer_2"
```

But when i change the ifelse to write best raster layer likes this code:

```
for(i in 1:length(list_files)){
  r <- stack(list_files[i])
  len <- nlayers(r)
  if(len!=3)
    next
  r_1 <- sum(is.na(as.matrix(r[[1]])))
  r_2 <- sum(is.na(as.matrix(r[[2]])))
  r_3 <- sum(is.na(as.matrix(r[[3]])))
  ifelse((r_1 < r_2 & r_1 < r_3),writeRaster(x = r[[1]], filename = file_name[i], format = 'GTiff'),
         ifelse((r_2 < r_1 & r_2 < r_3)
                ,writeRaster(x = r[[2]], filename = file_name[i], format = 'GTiff')
                ,writeRaster(x = r[[3]], filename = file_name[i], format = 'GTiff')))
}
```

I expect R create 4 tiff file with the best layer but R creates just the first file and gave me this error:

> Error in rep(yes, length.out = len) :
> attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'

how can I fix this error???
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that you are using a vectorized function (`ifelse`) where you actually need plain old `if ... else`. Or, better, `i <- which.min(c(r_1, r_2, r_3))` and you don't need `if` at all:

```
rv <- sapply(r, function(rj) sum(is.na(as.matrix(rj))))
ind <- which.min(rv)
writeRaster(x = r[[ind]], filename = file_name[i], format = 'GTiff')
```

Explanation: after running the command for j in 1..3, `sapply` returns a vector of three numbers, `rv`. Then, `which.min` returns the position of the smallest value in that vector. To make the code a little more explicit, do:

```
count.nas <- function(rj) sum(is.na(as.matrix(rj)))
rv <- sapply(r, count.nas)
ind <- which.min(rv)
writeRaster(x = r[[ind]], filename = file_name[i], format = 'GTiff')
```

Since I don't have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I did not check this code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to better get at what you are after, I think

Example data

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
b <- brick(f)
b[[1]][1:12] <- NA
b[[2]][5:10] <- NA
b[[3]][1:10] <- NA
```

Function to find best layer

```
fun <- function(x){
    if (nlayers(x) > 1) {
        cnt <- freq(x, value=NA)
        which.min(cnt)
    } else {
        -1
    }
}
```

Use function

```
fun(b)
```

Then perhaps something like:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_files)) {
   b <- brick(list_files[i])   
   j <- fun(b)
   if (j > 0) {
     writeRaster(b[[j]], file_name[i])
   }
}
```